# Format double value to 2 decimal points and get comma separated currency format in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on project where I have to display price in following format.

```
250  -> 250.00
2500 -> 2,500.00
260500.33 -> 260,500.33
```

I though following approach gonna make this work but It's not working.

```
    double price = 2500;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    String format1 = df.format(price);
    System.out.println(format1); //250.00

    String format2 = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(format1);// Exception "Cannot format given Object as a Number"
    System.out.println(format2); //excepted 2,500.00
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DecimalFormat` and `NumberFormat` objects expect their objects to format to be some kind of number, not a string such as `format1`, so an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

You've passed an already formatted string `format1` to `format` instead of a number.  Pass `price` to `format` as you already did the first time you called it.

But the US locale `NumberFormat` won't give you any digits beyond the decimal point; you will see `2,500` printed.  If you want those 2 decimal digits, you can specify that format explicitly, similar to how you constructed `df`.

```
String format2 = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00").format(price);
```

Comment: Can you not use `DecimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2)` to ensure there's always two decimal places displayed?

Comment: Yes, using `NumberFormat`'s `setMinimumFractionDigits` will work.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to set two decimal points and comma separated.

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price);
```

Comment: It may return the currency code as part of the formatted results which can be very misleading if the same data is being viewed in different locales